# Global counter with iOS and Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm very new to Parse and trying to set up what is basically a voting app where I can collect data on how many times all users have pressed a button. I found some information on Atomic Increment Operations from Parse but I'm trying to have this feature be implemented as something like a singleton.

So if I wanted to do this for one user:

```
gameScore.incrementKey("score" byAmount:NSNumber(numberWithInt:10))
gameScore.saveInBackground()
```

How would I get the same implementation where all users can update the same counter?

Comment: Why can't you have all the users access the same table entry and update the same counter?

Comment: As an alternative, a better practice would be to keep a record of each vote and then have your server calculate the number of votes periodically.

Comment: I decided to use firebase instead, for the real time updates. You can see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve my problem by using Firebase instead of Parse. I wanted real-time updating and Firebase provided that with ease. Here's my code for the View Controller:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Firebase Test
//
//  Created by Cole Smith on 7/24/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Cole Smith. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var firebaseRef = Firebase(url: "[LINK TO FIREBASE]")
    var valueOfCounter: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func counterPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        valueOfCounter++
        incrementCounterToFirebase(valueOfCounter)
    }

    func incrementCounterToFirebase(intForSubmission: Int) {
        firebaseRef.setValue(intForSubmission)

        // Read data and react to changes
        firebaseRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
            snapshot in
            println("\(snapshot.key) -> \(snapshot.value)")
            self.counterLabel.text = "\(snapshot.value)"
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful though, that operation probably isn't atomic so with more users you'll start missing votes.  I've never used firebase, but they have something called a [transaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html) which is atomic.

Comment: That's a good idea. I assumed that setValue() was maybe atomic by default. Thanks for bringing that to my attention!